# Why one of these objects has prototype but not in the second?

Tags: javascript, object

```
const a = Object.create(null);
const b = {};
```

I want to know the difference between these two objects. When I tried these two in console I have found the second one is showing prototypes. But the first one showing nothing like that. Please try it in your console if didn't get me.

Comment: Well... yeah. `{}` is an object and has `Object.prototype`. But `Object.create(null)` explicitly creates an object with no prototype at all.

Comment: _"I want to know the difference between these two objects. When I tried these two in console I have found the second one is showing prototypes."_ There is a question and an answer. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Why one of them has prototype but not in the second.

Comment: You should edit your question and add your actual question. Many people don't read the comments before they downvote or vote to close a question.

Answer (score 0):

> The `Object.create()` method creates a new object, using an existing
> object as the prototype of the newly created object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

> All objects (with the exception of objects created with
> Object.create(null)) will have a constructor property. Objects created
> without the explicit use of a constructor function (such as object-
> and array-literals) will have a constructor property that points to
> the Fundamental Object constructor type for that object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor

Comment: "*All objects will have a constructor property.*" - that's confusing, if not wrong. They don't *have* it, they *inherit* it.

Comment: @Bergi That's a quote from MDN. If you want to fix it: _"Found a problem with this page? [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/mdn/content/blob/master/files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/constructor/index.html)"_

Comment: Sure, but you could not quote it :-) Back when MDN was a wiki, I would've already edited it.